# Method to use LEFT JOIN with columns with the same name

Tags: mysql

I am using `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *`, but I need to left join a table that has a column with the same name as the first one.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
    FROM {$this->_db} 
   LEFT JOIN $this->_db2 ON $this->_db2.calc_id = $this->_db.calc_id    
";
```

Any idea how to make this work, as now the value from the 2nd table is overwriting the fist one?

Comment: You can use table name to identify the column `tableName.ColumnName`

Comment: Why are you using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`?  That's only useful if you have a `LIMIT` on your query, which you don't.

Comment: Why not use the alias like you did with the ON clause?  (`Db2`. or `db`)?  `SELECT db.SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS as DBFOUNDROWS, db.*, DB2.*`  You may still get a duplicate column name but you can alias one of them for your needs.  not the cleanest, better to select the columsn from tableAlias.column name individually imo.

Comment: xqbert Thanks mate. It worked

Comment: Solution: SELECT $this->_db.*, $this->_db2.name AS calcname

Comment: @xQbert: FYI `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is not the name of a field in his table.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Answer (score 0):

Since you are joining a table with a field with the same name as another, you cannot use `SELECT *`.

You need to manually list the fields that you want in the `SELECT` statement.